# Strange "command not found" and "No such file or directory" errors

Tags: bash, zsh

Very strange errors of multiple forms:

1. Running `brew install c-ares` fails with `command not found`, seemingly not even executing `brew`:

   ```
   $ brew install c-ares
   -bash: brew install c-ares: command not found
   ```

   Yet `brew install cmake` executes `brew` as expected:

   ```
   $ brew install cmake
   Warning: Treating cmake as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/cmake
   Warning: cmake 3.25.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
   To reinstall 3.25.1, run:
     brew reinstall cmake
   ```
2. Cannot prepend `/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin` to `$PATH` with the error `No such file or directory`:

   ```bash
   $ export PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH
   -bash: export PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin: No such file or directory
   ```

   That folder does exist:

   ```bash
   $ [ -d /usr/local/opt/qt5/bin ] && echo "exists"
   exists
   ```

   As do all the others on `$PATH`:

   ```bash
   $ echo $PATH
   /usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
   $ for i in $(echo $PATH | awk -F: '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { print $i; }}'); do if [ -d "$i" ]; then echo "$i exists"; else echo "$i does not exist"; fi; done
   /usr/local/bin exists
   /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin exists
   /usr/bin exists
   /bin exists
   /usr/sbin exists
   /sbin exists
   /Library/TeX/texbin exists
   /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin exists
   /opt/X11/bin exists
   /Library/Apple/usr/bin exists
   ```

   Yet adding `/tmp` works:

   ```bash
   $ export PATH=/tmp/:$PATH
   $ echo $PATH
   /tmp/:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
   ```
3. Same errors with `zsh`:

   ```bash
   $ zsh
   % brew install c-ares
   zsh: command not found: brew install c-ares
   % brew install cmake
   Warning: Treating cmake as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/cmake
   Warning: cmake 3.25.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
   To reinstall 3.25.1, run:
     brew reinstall cmake
   % export PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH
   zsh: no such file or directory: export PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin:/tmp/:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
   ```

I'm quite baffled and don't know how to debug shell built-ins.

Nothing comes to mind of what recently changed that could cause this. I upgraded to Ventura 13.1 today hoping this would go away, but it was happening before the upgrade and continues to happen.

I tried restarting and it didn't help.

System information:

```bash
% system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType SPHardwareDataType | grep -v -e UUID -e UDID -e 'User Name' -e 'Computer Name' -e Serial
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 13.1 (22C65)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 22.2.0
      Boot Volume: MainDisk
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Disabled
      Time since boot: 22 minutes, 2 seconds

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro15,1
      Processor Name: 6-Core Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.6 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 6
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 9 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 16 GB
      System Firmware Version: 1916.60.2.0.0 (iBridge: 20.16.2059.0.0,0)
      OS Loader Version: 564.40.4~55
      Activation Lock Status: Enabled
```

Comment: Have you checked the `/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin/` directory is not empty?  What do you get when you issue the command `which brew`?

Comment: @Allan `$ ls /usr/local/opt/qt5/bin/ | wc -l` results in `49` and the directory contents look fine. `which brew` results in `/usr/local/bin/brew`. The strange thing is that `export PATH=/tmp/:$PATH` and `brew install cmake` both do not report the errors, respectively.

Comment: If the `which` command finds `brew` then your PATH is correct. I suspect something may be an issue with the Homebrew installation. Try reinstalling.

Comment: @Allan The problem seems to be more fundamental. I just uninstalled `brew`, re-installed it, and with a fresh brew (`brew doctor` returns clean), the problem is reproduced. I tried using `dtruss` on `zsh` to investigate the `export` error and it doesn't show anything obvious.

Comment: All those ‘command not found’ errors look like zsh is treating the _whole_ command line as the name of a command to run, instead of doing its normal word-splitting. One possible cause is that you typed non-breaking spaces, or some other type of space, instead of normal spaces (though the question text here _does_ have normal spaces). I can't think of any other reasons why zsh may not be splitting words properly, but I bet there are some.

Comment: @gidds Ahh, I think you're on to something! This all started with trying to [compile Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/BuildingAndInstalling#macos). If I copy/paste `brew install c-ares` from that page, it fails with the error, but if I type in the same command, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment from @gidds, both of the failing commands (`export` and `brew install`) were copy/pasted from the [compiling Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/BuildingAndInstalling#macos) page. Instead, manually duplicating the commands by typing them solved the issue. It seems some whitespace or control characters from the Wireshark page cause both `zsh` and `bash` on macOS to interpret the whole command as the name of the command to run instead of word-splitting.

Comment: Looking at the source of that web page, those commands do indeed use the NO-BREAK SPACE character (U+00A0) instead of the normal SPACE (U+0020). So that's almost certainly the cause! (Oddly enough, when I copy from Chrome and paste into the Terminal, they seem to revert to normal spaces; but that probably doesn't happen in other cases.) Is it possible to edit that web page, or inform someone who can?

Comment: FWIW, when that happens I do something like echo the command into od -c to see if there are weird invisible characters.

Comment: @gidds I've requested access to edit the wiki

Comment: @Alex If you have the `uni` command installed (e.g. via HomeBrew), then `uni identify 'some_string'` will list and identify each Unicode character in the string — so you don't have to remember/decode UTF-8 sequences. (That's how I discovered the above!)

Comment: FYI, the Wireshark page has been fixed at https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/BuildingAndInstalling and it will roll-out to the other link in the future